# Typesetting dollars in equations

Tags: bug, status-deferred, mathjax

[This answer](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/138402/683) contained the following excerpt:
$$ \delta(q_0,\lambda,\\\$) = (q_1,\\\$) $$
Unfortunately, the dollar signs are preceded by line breaks. Worse, this doesn't happen in the preview, so it's impossible to know before the post appears.

How to fix that?

Comment: Doh!  I meant to link to this: https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1748/755

Comment: @D.W.  So, one's a duplicate?

Comment: @Raphael I suspect they are related but it's not 100% clear to me exactly how.  They both relate to issues with dollar signs, and they're probably closely connected somehow, but the way the issue shows up seems to be slightly different in these two (in one, it causes extraneous line breaks; in other, it causes extraneous backslashes).

Comment: Thank you for reporting. We've forwarded this to Platform to look at as part of bug duty.

Comment: @Rosie Thanks! To clarify: why [tag:status-deferred] (reads like: not anytime soon) and not [tag:status-planned] (reads like: hang on, we'll have a look). To emphasize, this is a breaking issue for sites that use MathJax, so seeing it "deferred" worries me.