# Code blocks add extra backslash, if followed by a dollar sign

Tags: bug, status-deferred, mathjax, markdown

If you type the characters for "backslash dollar" inside a code block, extra backslashes are displayed.  Worse, the rendered output doesn't match the preview.  See the example below:

Markdown source:

[image: code block containing backslash dollar]

Output that is displayed in preview pane:

[image: in the preview pane it is displayed as backslash backslash dollar]

Rendered output:

`\\\$`

---

Live example:

```
\\\$
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for reporting. We sent this to Public Platform to look into as part of bug duty.

Comment: @Rosie Thanks! To clarify: why [tag:status-deferred] (reads like: not anytime soon) and not [tag:status-planned] (reads like: hang on, we'll have a look). To emphasize, this is a breaking issue for sites that use MathJax, so seeing it "deferred" worries me.

Comment: This was already reported several times on meta.SE: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/357702/rendering-bug-with-backslash-and-dollar-sign-on-mathjax-enabled-sites, https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/356953/mathjax-rendering-bug-with-escaped-dollar-sign-apparently-only-on-crypto-s, https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/358098/weird-line-break-in-latex-formula